# Windows 8.1 Laptop Gives 502 Bad Gateway on Many Websites

Tags: networking, windows-8, gateway

I have a Macbook Air and my wife has an 8.1 Windows laptop.

I am able to access the internet as expected.

On the Windows machine, on multiple websites, we get 502 Bad Gateway when accessing various websites. From what I can gather, it tends to be areas of websites that require login. For example, we cannot access the "My Orders" area of Amazon when using the Windows machine, but can access the same page as expected when using the Mac.

Any ideas about what might be happening here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's everything you need.
What's happening and why and how to solve.

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/502error.htm

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.